# Two videos playing one after another in processing

Tags: video, processing

I'm pretty new to processing, but I'm trying to make two video files to play one after another, but it plays only the first one and then stops. Thanks in advance for your suggestions!

```java
import processing.video.*;

Movie mov;
Movie mov2;

boolean mo = true;

void setup(){
  size(810, 540);

  if (mo == true){
  mov = new Movie(this, "Vid5.mp4");
  mov.play();
  }

  if (mov.time() >= mov.duration()){
  mov.stop();
  mo = false;
 }
 }

void movieEvent(Movie m){
  m.read();

  if (mo == false){
  mov2 = new Movie(this, "Vid1.mp4");
  mov2.play(); 
  }
}

void draw(){
  if (mo == true){ 
  image(mov, 0, 0, width, height);
  } else {
  image (mov2, 0, 0, width, height);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code would be much easier to read with proper indentation. Just press `ctrl+t` in your Processing editor, and it will auto-indent for you.

But your main problem is because you only ever check whether the first movie is done playing **once**, at the very beginning of your sketch in the `setup()` function.

Instead, you need to continually check whether the movie is done. You could do this from the `draw()` function instead. Something like this:

```java
import processing.video.*;

Movie mov;
Movie mov2;

boolean mo = true;

void setup() {
  size(810, 540);

  mov = new Movie(this, "Vid5.mp4");
  mov.play();
}

void movieEvent(Movie m) {
  m.read();
}

void draw() {
  if (mo == true) { 
    image(mov, 0, 0, width, height);
  } else {
    image (mov2, 0, 0, width, height);
  }

  if (mo && mov.time() >= mov.duration()) {
    mov.stop();
    mo = false;
    mov2 = new Movie(this, "Vid1.mp4");
    mov2.play();
  }
}
```

Note that this code is untested, so you might have to tinker with it a bit, but the basic answer is that you need to check whether the first movie is done more than just once at the beginning of your sketch.

Comment: It works! Thank you so much! Thanks for explaining the mistake!